# Limit From the Right: Showing It Goes to Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am trying to show $\lim_{x\to 4^+}\frac{(-x+7)(x+8)}{x-4}=\infty$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $M>0$. Assume $0<x-4<\delta$. Show $\frac{(-x+7)(x+8)}{x-4}>M$.

Note $0<x-4\implies 4<x$. So, $x+8>12$.

Also, we have $-x+7>0$ for when $x\in (4, 7)$.

> At this point, I don't know where to go in the proof. I can manipulate $\frac{1}{x-4}>\frac{M}{(-x+7)(x+8)}$. But this doesn't seem to do anything when choosing $\delta$. I could simplify $(-x+7)(x+8)$ but I feel there is an easier way to approach this problem as there could be more than just these terms in the numerator.

Comment: We don't need to be concerned about $x\ge 5$ nor $x\le 4.$ If $x=4+d$ with $0<d<1, $ then $(-x+7)(x+8)/(x-4)>1/(x-4)=1/d,$  with $d\to 0^+ .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x-4<\delta$ then $0>4-x>-\delta$ and $3>7-x>3-\delta$ and $12<x+8<\delta+12$

$36-12\delta<(7-x)(x+8)<3\delta+36$, $\frac{1}{x-4}>\frac{1}{\delta}$

$\frac{36-12\delta}{\delta}=\frac{36}{\delta}-12<\frac{(7-x)(x+8)}{x-4}$

if we let $\delta < \frac{36}{M+12}$, then $\frac{(7-x)(x+8)}{x-4}>M$

Comment: Do you know if this process works with multiple values up top where the $\delta$'s get to be too much? For example, we want $M<\frac{36}{\delta}-12$ which works nicely here because with some algebra it can be shown that we instead choose $\delta<\frac{36}{M+12}$. I'd be curious to see how this works which is why I am asking.

Comment: Your answer does answer this question above. I am wondering if there ever is a situation with the part $M<\frac{36}{\delta}-12$ (i.e. where you figure out what to let $\delta$ be) is something way more complicated where there are multiple terms like $8-x$ and $9-x$ causing there to be multiple $\delta$'s. For example, instead of $M<\frac{36}{\delta}-12$ it was something more like $M<5\delta^2+\delta+7$ where we couldn't get to choose $\delta$ so easily. Does that ever happen?

Comment: Oh! ok, sure, I'm not sure I can answer that in general, but say we had $\frac{24}{\delta^2}+\frac{36}{\delta}-12$, then we're only after an approximation, assuming $\delta <1$ then $\delta^2<\delta$ and $\frac{1}{\delta^2}>\frac{1}{\delta}$ then $\frac{24}{\delta}+\frac{36}{\delta}-12= \frac{60}{\delta}-12< \frac{24}{\delta^2}+\frac{36}{\delta}-12$ and we are back to a linear approximation $M<\frac{60}{\delta}-12$

Answer (score 2):

If $4<x<5$ then $\frac {(-x+7)(x+18)} {x-4} >\frac {(-5+7)(22)} {x-4}$ and this is greater than $M$ if  $x<4+\frac {44} M$. So choose $4 <x< \min \{5, 4+\frac  {44} M\}$.

In other words, if $0<\delta < \frac {44} M$ and $\delta <1$, then $4<x<4+\delta$ implies $\frac {(-x+7)(x+18} {x-4} >M$.

Comment: This answer was also very useful. Thank you for your help!